# How to keep div width 50% on text change?

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs` with `width: 50%` and text content inside that are wrapped in the container. The problem is that when text content changes, width also changes:

[image: text1]

[image: text2]

I have a fixed width of the container equal to `200px`:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.text1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}

.text2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='text1'>Text1</div>
  <div class='text2'>Text2</div>
</div>
```

How I can keep 50% of child `div` width even when text is changing?
Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxk3cdpL/):

Comment: You may use [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355) in SO next time and I already do it for you now.

Comment: use display:inline-block

Comment: Maybe [this is good for you?](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/yhfboL9q/)

Comment: look at http://jsfiddle.net/rhn8u1pz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) here:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.text1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.text2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='text1'>Text1</div>
  <div class='text2'>Text2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Solution

`inline` elements only consume the the width that its content specifies.

Go for `display: block;` with `float: left;` or `display: flex` implementation.

**`display: block` implementation**

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.text1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.text2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='text text1'>1</div>
  <div class='text text2'>Text2</div>
</div>
```

**`display: flex` implementation**

In case of `flex` layout, there is no need to specify width to the child elements. Just add `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1` to the child elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
}

.text1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.text2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='text text1'>1</div>
  <div class='text text2'>Text2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although flexbox should work, as given by other responses, you can also do it by using **columns**.

Just specify **column-count** to 2 columns on **.container** and set **column-width** to 50% on **.text1** and **.text2**.

Here´s  it:

```
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  column-count: 2;
}

.text1 {
  background-color: red;
  column-width: 50%;
}

.text2 {
  background-color: blue;
  column-width: 50%;
}

<div class='container'>
     <div class='text1'>1</div>
     <div class='text2'>Text2</div>
</div>
```

Here´s the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mpbgs5n/).